# How to fix overlapping of x-axis labels while plotting a countplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way I can set a range for `'Age'` values in the countplot? The `minimum` value would be `23` and `maximum` `85`. I wanted to display it like this: `23-33 , 33-43`....

There are about 245,000 records with ages which range from `23` to `85` years in the `X-axis`. The labels for this specific axis are getting overlapped, as you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjcJK.png), for reference.

And this is the code I have so far:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(11,11))

sns.countplot(ax=axes[0,0],x='Age',hue='Credit_Product',data=df)
#ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")

sns.countplot(ax=axes[0,1],x='Gender',hue='Credit_Product',data=df)

sns.countplot(ax=axes[1,0],x='Region_Code',hue='Credit_Product',data=df)

sns.countplot(ax=axes[1,1],x='Occupation',hue='Credit_Product',data=df)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=1.1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))
```

Comment: Please ensure code is placed inside code block (format them properly). This provides clarity when users attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the official Titanic data, I created a similar graph. The gist can be achieved by replacing the x-axis with an array that matches the number of ticks on the x-axis. I actually created an empty list of the number of ages and updated the array with 6 age range strings (23-32,etc). There may be a better way than this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
titanic.dropna(subset=['age'], inplace=True)
titanic['age'] = titanic['age'].astype(int)
titanic.query('age >= 23', inplace=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(11,11))

sns.countplot(x="age", hue='sex', data=titanic, ax=axes[0,0])
sns.countplot(x="sex", hue='class', data=titanic, ax=axes[0,1])
sns.countplot(x="embark_town", hue='class', data=titanic, ax=axes[1,0])
sns.countplot(x="class", hue='sex', data=titanic, ax=axes[1,1])

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=1.1)

ticks = axes[0,0].get_xticklabels()
age_seg = ['23-32','33-42','43-52','53-62','63-72','73-82']
new_ticks = ['' for x in range(len(ticks))]
k = 0
for i in range(len(ticks))[::8]:
    new_ticks[i+3] = age_seg[k]
    k += 1

axes[0,0].set_xticklabels(new_ticks)
#plt.tight_layout()
#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))

plt.show()
```

[image]